# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: virtualbox

I've read a lot about this issue but I have not yet managed to solve. I use Ubuntu 16.10 (64 bit) and virtualbox taken from "ubuntu software". Can someone help me?

This is the output with the command (as root)

```
$ dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii
ii  unity-scope-virtualbox         0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1  all          VirtualBox scope for Unity
ii  virtualbox                     5.1.6-dfsg-2                 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-dkms                5.1.6-dfsg-2                 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-qt                  5.1.6-dfsg-2                 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
ii  virtualbox-source              5.1.6-dfsg-2                 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module source
```

I delete the secure boot and I turned on the Virtualization Technology (int the bios)

If I start VirtualBox as root with terminal the error (showed in the terminal) is:

```
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Comment: I assume that you mean Ubuntu 16.10? In the `terminal`, show me the output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii`. Edit the results into your question.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer by the OP**

I solved by starting the machine with USB 1.1 (OHCI) in the USB settings